# Subsonic 3 - Insert of Update

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3, subsonic-active-record

Currently using Subsonic 3 with Activerecord. Purely out of curiosity, is there an easy way to update or insert a record in a clean and consise way?

Instead of

```
 var record = MyModal.SingleOrDefault(x => x.id == 1)
 if (record != null)
 {
     // code to update record here
 } else {
    // code to insert a record here
    MyModal record = new MyModal();
    record.attribute1 = "blah"
    ... blah blah
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard ActiveRecord templates provide a Save() method, which either calls Add() or Update() depending on whether the object IsNew(). It should work in the sample you gave.

Answer (score 0):

You should also be able to do it like this:

```
            // perform insert with a linq expression
            db.Insert.Into<PARTS_VI_PART_NUMBER>(
                x => x.ITEM_NUMBER,
                x => x.ITEM_CLASS_CODE,
                x => x.ITEM_DESCRIPTION,
                x => x.MANUFACTURER
            ).Values(
                "TEST",
                "TEST",
                "TEST",
                "TEST"
            ).Execute();

            // update using linq expression
            db.Update<PARTS_VI_PART_NUMBER>()
                .Set(x => x.ITEM_DESCRIPTION == "UPDATED",
                     x => x.ITEM_CLASS_CODE == "UPDATED2")
                .Where(x => x.ITEM_NUMBER == "TEST")
                .Execute();

            // delete inserted row with a linq expression
            db.Delete<PARTS_VI_PART_NUMBER>(x => x.ITEM_NUMBER == "TEST").Execute();
```

At least that is how I've been doing it in one of my projects.
The `Insert()`, `Update()` and `Delete()` methods are generated by `Context.tt` into the `Context.cs` file (I am using the "ActiveRecord" T4 files).

---

*Edit*

Oh I'm sorry, when I forst read your question, I thought you were asking for an easier way to *"Insert" or "Update"*, but after re-reading it, I realized you are asking for *"Insert, or Update if it already exists"* like doing an 'upsert'.

Sorry, my answer doesn't really cover that.  I don't know of a good way to do it either.  I usually just end up doing what you are doing... try to select it, and if I get no results, do the insert.

Comment: Just wish it had Rails' find_or_create helper method :P

Comment: It is an open-source project... feel free to add one ;)  Unfortunately, that is one of those things that isn't well supported. Ansi sql provides for a `merge into` statement, but not every DB implements it. Some have their own syntax. I don't think it would be impossible to add to SubSonic. Its just some work to add it for every supported DB, and test it.